# Performing both client side and server side functions on button click - Specific Scenario

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox, label and button control.
If the checkbox is not checked and button is clicked, I need to display a message in label stating to check the checkbox first.
If the checkbox is checked and then the button clicked, it should allow me to proceed.

This is very similar to the terms and conditions screens,where if you dont check the checkbox - you are not allowed to proceed.

I am using the below javascript. Please let me know how do I accomplish this functionality?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testCheckbox() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('<%= chkTerms.ClientID %>');
    if (obj.checked == false) {
        document.getElementById("lblCheck").style.visibility = "visible";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<asp:Label ID="lblTerms" runat="server" Text="I agree to the Terms and Conditions">   </asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lblCheck" runat="server" Text="Please agree to the terms and conditions to proceed"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" OnClientClick ="return testCheckbox()"   OnClick="btnProceed_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: in above code you have 2 label and 1 button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lblCheck').hide();
        $('#btnProceed').click(function () {
            var $this = $('#chkTerms')

            if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                $('#lblCheck').hide();
                return true;
            } else {
                $('#lblCheck').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkTerms" runat="server" Text="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"/><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblCheck" runat="server" Text="Please agree to the terms and conditions to proceed"/><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnProceed_Click1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnProceed_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("DD");
    //your proceed
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samiey Mehdi. I tried with the earlier resolution you provided with enabled view state property of label to false,but it didnt work as expected. Let me try with the jquery you provided now.

Comment: Its not working @Samiey. On page load, it shows the label text-         Please agree to the terms and conditions to proceed

Comment: Page Load is the problem I guess. Somehow we need to make the text not visible.

Comment: It worked so smoothly.You are a champ.I need to get my hands dirty on jquery...Thanks @Samiey Mehdi